# prometheus how to change instance name

Tags: prometheus

```json
  "targets": [ "10.123.175.30:9100", "10.125.150.14:9100" ],
    "labels": {
      "env": "dev",
      "job": "node",
      "group": "developer"
    }
```

for those targets, can I map those IP addresses to instance name ?
such as `host1:9100`, `host2:9100` (Grafana will have better display then.)

or modify `/etc/hosts` is best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to feed in the host name to Prometheus in the first place, rather than an IP address. Prometheus will resolve it when scraping.

Comment: Thanks brian, I will use /etc/hosts for this.

Comment: Is there a way to use metric_relabel_configs or a recording rule to calculate the hostname and then place it into the `instance` label? I'm wondering this because I have my prometheus setup to scrape localhost for prometheus metrics but it would be nice if localhost was replaced with an actual host name.

Answer (score 3):

`instance` label can be overridden via `labels` section inside [static_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config):

```yaml
- scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node_exporter
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["10.123.175.30:9100"]
      labels:
        instance: host-foo
    - targets: ["10.125.150.14:9100"]
      labels:
        instance: host-bar
```

Answer (score 0):

We can update instance to use the host ip and the port:

```
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip, __address__]
          target_label: instance
          regex: (.*);.*:(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
```

Or you can use the node name from this meta data, and also can check the others, from this url:

```
http://prometheus:9090/service-discovery?search=
__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name="node1"
```